# classを別ファイルから使用する

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6

es6からcalssが使えるようになりましたが，c#のように他のファイルでclassを書いてから使用する方法を教えてください。
（環境はnode.jsでコマンドプロンプト上で実行しています）

[マルチポスト](https://teratail.com/questions/89887)

Comment: Node.jsの実行環境が手元にないので、参考リンク(英語版stackoverflowより)のご提示のみで失礼: [Node.js ES6 classes with require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684177/node-js-es6-classes-with-require).

Comment: ありがとうございます。これを参考に手元でやってみるとうまくいきました

Answer (score 3):

コメントのリンクを参考に以下のようにすればうまくいきました。
class編集側のファイル

```
module.exports = class Cat{
// クラスの中み
}
```

利用側のファイル

```
const Cat = require(./ファイル名);
let cat = new Cat;
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6の場合、クラスの定義は下記で

```js
export default class Cat {
}
```

使用する側はこれでいいかと思います。

```js
import Cat from 'Cat';
```

上記を実行する際はbabelでトランスパイルする必要があります。追記させていただきましたm(__)m

Comment: これは将来の話ですか？ それとも既に Node.js で動きますか？

Comment: v4.8.4以上であれば問題ないかと思います。下記リンク先にNode.jsのバージョンとES6の対応表があります。
実行環境のNode.jsのバージョンは何でしょうか？

http://node.green/#ES2015-functions-class

Comment: v6.11.2 で試しましたが、ES6 のモジュールはサポートされていないようです。ざっと見ただけですが、お示しいただいたリンク先にも、ES6 のモジュールシステムに関する記述がないように思います。@Tomokazu Kozuma さんはどういった環境でテストされていますか？ 気づかない内に何らかのビルドシステムが走っていたりしないですか？

Comment: あ、失礼しました。moduleに関してはbabelでトランスパイルしないといけないですね。
自分の技術ブログですが、babelの導入方法を書いているのでもしよければ参考にしていただければと思います。
http://tomokazu-kozuma.com/how-to-set-up-es6/